# How do I suppress code generation errors caused by classes which failed to be generated?

Tags: android, android-studio, code-generation, dagger-2, android-databinding

Using libraries like Android data binding, Dagger 2, Requery, GreenDAO, and many others, Android project compilation often depends upon classes generated at compile-time.

When mistakes are made that inhibit correct code generation in a large project, instead of seeing the error about that issue highlighted, Android Studio reports errors from hundreds of missing classes and related issues. I have to dig to find the real error embedded among hundreds of lines of missing class errors and related errors and warnings. As the project grows in scope, code generation errors become unmanageable.

Is there any method to inhibit these anticipated errors in cases when code generation goes awry so I can quickly see the cause without digging into false positives?

Comment: I am interested in this question too : we are using Data Binding and if we make a mistake in our Dagger setup then the relevant error message is buried amidst a mass of Data Binding errors. I love the error messages for Dagger 2 which I find much more helpful than the error messages I was getting from Guice so it would be great if somehow we could isolate them.

Answer (score 0):

The real causes of errors contains at gragle build log. You need to open **Gradle console**. It's looks like on image below:

[image: Error log example]

Comment: This produced over 100 errors mostly unrelated to the root cause. It's might even be harder to read than Messages. Is there a particular Gradle version required for this to work?

Comment: I use latest build tool version (25.0.2). Usually, the real reason of error placed at the end of build trace